# Seed Region Growing Threshold

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I have this matrix

[image]

The following points

- R1 = (1,7) = 0
- R2 = (3,2) = 6
- R3 = (5,5) = 3
- R4 = (7,3) = 1

And using this equation `|g(seedi) – g(pixel)| < T`
for T=1

And this is the solution for threshold = 1[image]

I don't understand why all the ones for example, belong to R1 = `α`

Based on the equation we have `|0 - 1| < 1`, which means it shouldn't become `α`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your seed locations and the threshold of 1, that means that not every pixel can be labelled. See below.
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
5 & 6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \require{enclose}\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{0}}\\
6 & 7 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 6\\
3 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}} & 7 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 3 & 7 & 7& 7 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & 3 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 1 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
\end{array}\\
\Huge \updownarrow\\
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
5 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} &\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \require{enclose}\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{0}} & \require{enclose}\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{0}}\\
\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}} & 7 & 7 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}}\\
\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}} & 7 & 7 & 7 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="green"]{\color{black}{6}} & 5\\
4 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & 7 & 7& 7 & 5 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}}\\
\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & 2 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}} & 4\\
2 & 2 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & 2 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & 2 & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="blue"]{\color{black}{3}}\\
\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & \enclose{circle}[mathcolor="cyan"]{\color{black}{1}} & 2 & 2\\
\end{array}\\
$$
It looks like there should be 4 labels, not three... and, yes, it looks like the 0 and 1 seeded regions have been merged.

In addition to the lack of labels for all pixels (3 vs 4), I wonder if it's because the calculations are being done in (double precision) floating point so that $|1.00 - 0.00| < 1.00$